# How to handle dragend event in Netflix video

Tags: javascript, react-redux, rxjs, dom-events

I have a Chrome Extension that does some basic automation against Netflix. I have this line that performs a *skip* backward or forward:

```
netflix.cadmium.UiEvents.events.resize[1].scope.events.dragend[trickyIndex].handler(null, {value: 123, pointerEventData: {playing: true}});
```

When `trickyIndex` is 1 it works perfectly ***only if*** the Netflix slider remains untouched. If the viewer drags the slider forward or back or uses the forward or back arrow keys to skip back or forward, the next time the above line is called, it throws one of the two following errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handler' of undefined

or...

> Cannot read property 'target' of null

The second error shown is by far the most common, but I have seen the first as well.

It appears they're using an Observable pattern with `RxJS` and `react-redux`.

But after the slider (or arrows) is moved by the viewer, the line above will work perfectly from then on if `trickyIndex` is 0. No matter how many times it's called again, or whether the user skips back or forward, a `trickyIndex` of 0 will always work but a `trickyIndex` of 1 will always throw the error shown above.

If I start out with a `trickyIndex` of 0 from the beginning, it throws the error. It only works correctly after the user does a manual skip with slider or arrows.

**The problem**: I don't know how to detect when the user drags the slider or uses the left/right arrow keys. If I could detect that, I could set `trickyIndex` correctly and I believe it would work in all cases. Or I would be open to a better or more robust to solution altogether. Another problem is that try/catch simply doesn't work around the line of code shown. I think because there's a handler involved that is async. If I could successfully catch the error, I could simply try 1 and, failing that, try 0, and that would probably work great. But the catch block catches nothing and the exception crashes its way all the way back to the browser.

I have additionally tried this approach, which runs completely error-free, but doesn't perform the seek/skip:

```
netflix.cadmium.UiEvents.events.resize.forEach(function(resizeItem) {
    if (resizeItem.scope) {
        resizeItem.scope.events.dragend.forEach(function(dragendItem) {
            if (dragendItem.scope) {
                dragendItem.handler(null, {
                    value: 123,
                    pointerEventData: {playing: true}
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I confirmed that the outer `foreach` is entered but not the inner `foreach` (`dragendItem.scope` is always null). Which is puzzling because if I run the origional line: `netflix.cadmium.UiEvents.events.resize[1].scope.events.dragend[trickyIndex].handler(null, {value: 123, pointerEventData: {playing: true}});` -- it does work in the particular use case.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, you'll need to dive into the actual site code to find the condition of the handler being registered in the `events`. Use devtools debugger: set breakpoints, including the conditional ones with `console.log('something')` that will spam in console whenever the bp line is hit.

Comment: The site code is obfuscated and hundreds of thousands of lines. I have tried the Chrome debugger but it's just a labyrinth of unintelligible code. Any idea how I can catch the exception at least?

Answer (score 1):

Netflix make [extensive use](http://techblog.netflix.com/2013/02/rxjava-netflix-api.html) of the [observable pattern](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html) both client and server side - anything you try to do with their events needs to take account of that.

In particular events become 'collections in time' that they then apply collection functions (such as `map`) across.

This design pattern doesn't leave event handlers lying around (it's one of its big advantages) so you won't be able to hold on to them, you'll need to hook in to the core observers or add your own.

This means using [Rx methods](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS), rather than indexes, as the index will constantly change as new events happen and old ones are discarded.

Something like this:

```
netflix.cadmium.UiEvents.events.resize.subscribe(
    // This will repeat every time resize happens
    r => r.scope.events.dragend.subscribe(
        // This will repeat every time dragend happens
        d => d.handler(null, {value: 123, pointerEventData: {playing: true}})
    )
);
```

[Netflix have been quite open about using Rx](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AslncyG8whg), and I strongly recommend that you watch their videos (they have a whole YouTube channel for their UI) if you're planning to build anything on top of it.

Comment: Keith: You said "probably impossible for security reasons". I can inject arbitrary js into their js scope, so shouldn't that make something possible? Not to disrupt it, just to skip/seek when needed. Did you have any ideas how to solve this, or at least how to catch the exception?

Comment: @HerrimanCoder _"probably impossible for security reasons"_ is due to the [isolated execution environment](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment). You might be able to work around it.
Your problem is that you're assuming that you have events, when really you have a for-each loop. In your example both `resize` and `dragend` are probably both [RxJS](http://rxjs.codeplex.com/) observables.

Comment: @HerrimanCoder This means those events you're hooking cease to exist once they have been called, with new 'next' events created instead. When `dragend` happens `netflix.cadmium.UiEvents.events.resize[1].scope.events.dragend[trickyIndex]` fires and then is discarded for `dragend[trickyIndex+1]` (and you get the first error). When `resize` happens `netflix.cadmium.UiEvents.events.resize[1]` fires and next up is `resize[2]` (and you get the second error message). You **can't** rely on indexes with observables, you need to use a loop or collection function to process them as an iteration.

Comment: FWIW [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879) shows how to inject code into the page context which the OP seems to know already.

Comment: @wOxxOm probably, but that's not actually their problem. The issue is that  they're trying to consume an Rx Observable as an event.

Comment: I'm already injecting my js into the page, else what I'm doing wouldn't work at all. It actually works great, as long as I get the correct index, which is what I don't know how to determine. Thanks everyone for your help with this. Any ideas on trapping that exception? It's a bit of a fail-and-fix approach but it would work great if I could do that. Also I was going to try a foreach, but `dragend` doesn't seem to have a length property.

Comment: Does anyone know how I could get `.handler()` to call a function rather than inline code? It seems if I could do that, I could place a try/catch inside that function and trap the error. Any ideas?

Comment: @HerrimanCoder `dragend` and `resize` are _observables_ - they are _iterations_ of events. They don't have a length because each time the event happens they move to the next value. Netflix have done [presentations in the past](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AslncyG8whg) that say they are using [`RxJS`, so go learn how to use it](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS). Your code should be something like: `netflix.cadmium.UiEvents.events.resize.subscribe(r => r.scope.events.dragend.subscribe(d => d.handler(null, {value: 123, pointerEventData: {playing: true}})));`

Comment: @Keith I tried your posted code and I get this error every time: `Uncaught TypeError: netflix.cadmium.UiEvents.events.resize.subscribe is not a function`. Any ideas?

Comment: @HerrimanCoder I'm guessing at the structure of the Netflix observables, I'm just trying to point you in the right direction. Basically: Netflix use observables, React and Rx. Their events will **not** work with indexes like you're trying to do. Find the observables and use the collection methods from Rx to consume their events.

Comment: @Keith thanks for your patience -- I have edited my original post to show my latest attempt: nested foreach'es that seem very promising - yet still no joy. Any idea why that wouldn't work? Also I went and watched 2 youtube videos about RxJS observables. Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139975/discussion-between-herrimancoder-and-keith).

Comment: @HerrimanCoder yeah, you already said. I'm just guessing at the entry point to the observable - you're going to have to figure out that bit for yourself. You may be better off with a whole new question, and this answers your original query about the 'tricky index' - I can tell you why the index doesn't work, but not exactly where the entry point is.